# jquery fade doesnt work after clone?

Tags: jquery, clone, fadein

I have a div that has an animation attached to it and the animation works perfectly, but when I clone it the effect does not work any more?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').bind('click', function () {
        var parents = $(this).parents('.display');
        parents.clone(true).appendTo('body');
    });
    $('img').fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <div style="display:block; position:relative;" class="display">
        <div>
            <button class="close">close</button>
            <h3>Camera Ready</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc...</p>
        </div>
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        var parents = $(this).parents(".display");
        parents.clone(true).appendTo("body").find("img").hide().fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("img").fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

I've added an extra `fadeIn` call after the clone.  `appendTo` returns the item you append, so that should fade in any cloned elements.

Incidentally, I replaced `bind` with `on` as that is now the more preferred method, but that depends on whether you're using an up-to-date version of jQuery or not.

Here's a working fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/G2Wxu/2/

Note that I also added `display:none` to the css so that the initial image fades in.

Comment: i want after clone the image inside .display fade in but after clone it doesnt fade in

Comment: The above script will fade in the new image when the div is cloned.

Comment: @Archer did you try it? It will not fadeIn the element because the element is already displayed on the page. http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/G2Wxu/1/

Comment: This works now - thanks @DimaKuzmich.  The image is hidden and then fades in...  http://jsfiddle.net/G2Wxu/2/

Comment: Yes I already posted the working example down on the page :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, your

`$('img').fadeIn("slow");`

code is outside the click function.

That results in only being run the first time the page loads.

Comment: what should i do could you suggest somethinf

Answer (score 0):

Because you bind it on `document.ready`. After `.append`, you have to rebind it.

Comment: hamed jaj age mitooni javab beded giram

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/G2Wxu/) You must to hide your element before you trigger fadein:

```
var newEl = parents.clone(true).appendTo('body');
newEl.find('img').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```